# How to output empty line when recieving an empty string in while loop in java?

Tags: java, string, while-loop

I was trying to create a calculator that reads from 0 to 2 numbers from a single line.
If it recieves to numbers, it adds them up. If only one integer is entered, then it duplicates it as an output. If line is empty then calculator shoud also output an empty line immediatelly and continue asking for an input. However, it does so, but not immediatelly and it skips lines only when the next line of number(s) is entered.
So here is my code

```
package calculator;

import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String input = scanner.nextLine();
            //for the sake of stopping the code
            if (input.equals("/exit")) {
                System.out.println("Bye!");
                break;
            } else if (input.isEmpty()){
                System.out.println();
            }
            else{
                String[] array = input.split(" ");
                int[] numbers = new int[array.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
                    numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(array[i]);
                }
                int sum = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
                    sum += numbers[i];
                }
                System.out.println(sum);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

UPDATE

fixed by changing scanner.hasNext() to scanner.hasNextLine() fixed the problem.

Comment: The scanner, 'nextLine' is not returning until it receives a non-empty line. Then it receives all of them. How about a bufferedreader?

Comment: `while (scanner.hasNext()) {` should probably be `while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `Scanner.hasNext` was blocking until a non-empty input. Replacing it with `Scanner.hasNextLine` doesn't block if there is an empty line.

Here is how to do it with a `BufferedReader`. It will return when you press enter even with a blank line.

```
import java.io.*;
public class Main{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
     BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
     boolean running = true;
     while( running ){
       String line = r.readLine();

       System.out.println("recv: " + line);
     }
  }
}
```